# Error de conexión al obtener datos del mercado a través de la API de XTB en Python

Tags: python, api, script

en python para conectarlo con XTB, El error que estoy teniendo dice que la conexión con el servidor remoto se cerró sin respuesta

El problema es que al intentar establecer una conexión con la API de XTB en Python para obtener datos del mercado. Al ejecutar el código, se produce un error de conexión que indica que la conexión remota fue cerrada sin recibir una respuesta del servidor.

He verificado que estoy utilizando la dirección correcta de la API proporcionada en la documentación de XTB, que es "xapi.xtb.com". También he verificado que las credenciales de autenticación (usuario y contraseña) que estoy utilizando son correctas.

Sin embargo, a pesar de estos pasos, sigo obteniendo el error de conexión. Esto puede indicar que hay un problema de red o algún otro problema en la configuración de la API, pero no lo encuentro y me va a explotar la cabezaaa. gracias

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

REAL_USER = "xxxxx"  
REAL_PASS = "xxxxx"  
REAL_URL = "https://xapi.xtb.com:5112"

def obtener_datos(symbol, interval):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {REAL_USER}:{REAL_PASS}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    params = {
        "command": "getChartRangeRequest",
        "symbol": symbol,
        "period": interval,
        "start": 0,
        "end": 120
    }
    response = requests.get(f"{REAL_URL}/chart", headers=headers, params=params)
    print("URL de la solicitud:", response.url)
    print("Código de estado de la respuesta:", response.status_code)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()["data"]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df["t"] = pd.to_datetime(df["t"], unit="s")
        df.columns = ["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]
        return df
    else:
        print("Error en la solicitud a la API")
        return None
```